# trading view pine script strategy backtest error

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

im new to this, please advise what am i doing wrong?

TRADINGview pinescript strategy backtest EMAs crossovers of the 13-day and 48.5-day averages

i get this error

Compilation error. Line 11: no viable alternative at input 'if'. Try to add line '//@version=2' to the top of your script

```
// Set the lookback periods for the EMAs
lookbackShort = 13
lookbackLong = 48.5

// Calculate the short and long EMAs
emaShort = ema(close, lookbackShort)
emaLong = ema(close, lookbackLong)

// Check if the short EMA crosses above the long EMA
if crossover(emaShort, emaLong)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

// Check if the short EMA crosses below the long EMA
if crossunder(emaShort, emaLong)
    strategy.exit("Close Long", "Long", strategy.close)

// Plot the EMAs on the chart
plot(emaShort, color=red)
plot(emaLong, color=blue)
```

im new to this, please advise what am i doing wrong?

TRADINGview pinescript strategy backtest EMAs crossovers of the 13-day and 48.5-day averages

i get this error

Compilation error. Line 11: no viable alternative at input 'if'. Try to add line '//@version=2' to the top of your script

Answer (score 0):

Few issues here:

1. The error message is clear. Add the version number to the top of your script.
2. You can't call the `ema` function with a `float`. It needs to be an `int` (whole number).
3. Your `strategy.exit` function has to have a an exit price (or the difference in ticks from purchase price). If you want to close the position in market order, you'll need to use `strategy.close()` function.

```
//@version=2
strategy("ema")
// Set the lookback periods for the EMAs
lookbackShort = 13
lookbackLong = 48

// Calculate the short and long EMAs
emaShort = ema(close, lookbackShort)
emaLong = ema(close, lookbackLong)

// Check if the short EMA crosses above the long EMA
if crossover(emaShort, emaLong)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

// Check if the short EMA crosses below the long EMA
if crossunder(emaShort, emaLong)
    strategy.close("Long")

// Plot the EMAs on the chart
plot(emaShort, color=red)
plot(emaLong, color=blue)
```